# Countifs with reference in an array

Tags: excel, countif

I'm trying to use countifs with reference to the value in another cell. No issue so far, except when the reference is being used within an array of value.

Short example:
(arrays used with a single value for this example, but that's just to shorten the example)

```
    =COUNTIFS(B:B;">="&A1) --> does work  
    =COUNTIFS(B:B;{">="&A1}) --> returns an error
```

Same issue if I try to nest a formula within the array

```
    =COUNTIFS(B:B;">="&EDATE(TODAY();-6)) --> does work
    =COUNTIFS(B:B;{">="&EDATE(TODAY();-6)}) --> returns an error
```

Full example:

Consider those values

```
|    A     |    B    |
|----------|---------|
| =today() | 1/1/15  |
|----------|---------|
|          |         |
|----------|---------|
|          | 1/7/15  |
|----------|---------|
|          |         |
|----------|---------|
|          | 1/1/16  |
|----------|---------|
|          | 1/7/16  |
|----------|---------|
```

Note that the date notation is d/m/aa (months in the middle).

What I want to achieve is to count all the dates in column B that are greater that a given date OR equals space.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B1:B6;{">=42483";""})) --> does work and returns 3 (42483 being today's value)
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B1:B6;{">="&A1;""})) --> error in formula
```

Same issue with a formula if I want to count all the dates for the past 6 months OR space cells.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B1:B6;{">=42300";""})) --> does work and returns 4 (42300 being 6 months ago's value)
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B1:B6;{">="&EDATE(TODAY();-6);""})) --> error in formula
```

Any idea if that's even possible ?
Thanks

Comment: Why the array of one cell?  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Again it does not make sense as to what you are trying to do.  You are trying to make an array out of one value.  A1 is one value `EDATE(TODAY();-6)` is one value.  So I repeat my question what are you actually trying to do?  Paste an example of data and expected outcomes.  It will help us understand your though process.

Comment: That was just for the example. My real goal is with several values of course. But it doesn't change anything to the initial issue.

Comment: =SUM(COUNTIFS(B:B;{">="&A1;""})) --> test if greater than a given value (in cell A1) OR if equals space --> but the issue remains

Comment: Show some data and expected outcome.

Comment: The way to do that is `COUNTIFS(B:B,">="&A1,B:B,"=")`

Comment: Post edited, thanks :)

Comment: Try variants of this `=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B5>=A1)*1)+SUMPRODUCT((B1:B5="")*1)`

Comment: For the COUNTIFS solution `COUNTIFS(B:B,">="&A1,B:B,"=")`, this will check if column B's content is greater than A1 **AND** equals to space, isn't it ? While what I try to do is greater than A1 **OR** equals to space, in a single formula, without summing 2 different countifs (hence the use of the array). Is that possible ?

Comment: No, Countifs() by definition is AND centric.  The only way around is to do the + of two or `SUMPRODUCT((B1:B5>=A1)+(B1:B5=""))` with sumproduct.

Comment: That's not the only way, see the example in my original post using countifs: `=SUM(COUNTIFS(B1:B6;{">=42483";""}))` --> (42483 being today's value) -> returns 3 because of one date being greater than today and 2 cells being  = space. So thanks to the array you can simulate an **OR** statement (cells > 42483 **OR** cells = space). The whole purpose of this post is to know if it's possible to refer to another cells value in the array (or to use a formula directly in the array)

Answer (score -3):

Your semi-colon needs to be a comma. Try:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,">="&A1)
```

Comment: This is not the issue.  Semicolon is commonly used instead of comma in different regional areas (like France for example).

Comment: Thanks for the info Mr tigeravatar, I was unaware of that. However, don't you think that it would have been more helpful to the poster to post the solution than neg me for a providing a solution that works for me [rhetorical question].

Comment: The problem is we do not understand the question, as what the OP is asking does not make sense, see my comments above.  There are many who would happily answer the question if the question made sense.  You are getting down voted because the information you provided as an answer is inherently wrong and if it remains it is important that future viewers of this post do not get side tracked by errant information.  So Just because it works for you it still is not the right answer and is misleading for those who use `;` as the deliminator in their functions.